# Having problems using moment.js on Heroku

Tags: javascript, node.js, heroku, momentjs, parse-server

I used to have some cloud code on Parse using `moment.js`.

The first relevant line of code inside my `main.js` file was:

```
var moment = require('cloud/moment.js');
```

Now on Parse-Server I get the following error message in the logs:

```
Starting process with command `npm start`

 > parse-server-example@1.4.0 start /app
 > node index.js

 module.js:471
     throw err;
     ^
Error: Cannot find module 'moment.js'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:469:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:417:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/app/cloud/main.js:1:76)
    at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
```

***Can someone tell me what is happening?***

After reading quite a bit on the net I have tried a few things, like:

```
var moment = require('./cloud/moment.js');
var moment = require('moment.js');
```

All failed.

I am sure that the file moment.js is present under my cloud folder.
I have also tried to install a new version of moment(from: https://momentjs.com/), but to no avail.

Checking the `package.json` file, it contains the following:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "~4.11.x",
    "kerberos": "~0.0.x",
    "moment": "^2.17.1",
    "parse": "~1.8.0",
    "parse-server": "*"
  },
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is likely caused by this line:

`var moment = require('moment.js');`

It should be:

`var moment = require('moment');`

The first line looks for a specific file in your file tree, rather than a package. The second line looks for the package 'moment.js.'

Comment: It sounds like you are right. I stopped getting the error. So I used to use a simple file, I am now using a package. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Glad to be of assistance!

Answer (score 0):

Add `moment` to your `package.json` file and let Heroku install it, then just do `var moment = require('moment.js');`

Just add this line `"moment": "^2.14.1"` to the dependencies section of your `package.json` file.

In general you want to add your dependencies using `npm install --save <libraryname>` so it would be added to the `package.json` file.

You can do that; `npm install --save moment` as an alternative solution.

Comment: Thanks, but I just checked the package.json file, and it contains what you say  (or similar). I just edited my post to reflect that. So what is missing?

Comment: replace this line var moment = require('cloud/moment.js'); by this var moment = require('moment'); don't putt them together

Comment: This is what I did. I still get the same error.

var moment = require('moment.js');

is the first line of my file main.js